# how to remove such character from html page?

Tags: html, unicode

how can i remove � �  this question mark from the unicode characters at home page ? i have already defined charset=utf-8 at header but still getting those question marks

Comment: What are they supposed to be? How did those characters get there? Do you pull that from a database or is it text you've written?

Comment: i pull it from mysql database and db column is set to utf_general_ci

Answer (score 1):

Try running the query `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'")` (or `dbh->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'")`, or whatever you use) before you pull the data from the database and see how that goes.